# Early optimized/broken caster

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

My DM is about to run us through a heck of a campaign. I don't know what to expect, but he has told us that anything goes. All non-homebrew source flies, and he has challenged us to make the most powerful characters we can. I have done quite a bit of research, and have learned about some really broken things such as tainted scholar, incantatrix, shadowcraft mage, etc.. The thing is we only start at level 3, and I know this guy is going to be trying to kill us right out of the gate. I need an optimized/broken caster that gets going as soon as possible. I'm not looking for Pun-pun levels of broken, but pretty much anything else goes. We have a healer, so I don't absolutely have to have divine casting. It would be nice, though. I will be filling the sorc/wiz slot of the party, so skirting around spells per day, spells known, etc. would be nice. I've even heard of a way to get spells as a free action, though I have no clue how or if it's  End game brokenness is extremely important, but early access to overpowered glory may be important to making it to that point.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what you *do* want to be able to do?

Comment: Welcome. Please check out our tour found here: rpg.stackexchange.com/tour, it will show you what a Stack Exchange site like this one is and is not equipped to do. This prompt would work great on a message board but that's not what we are. Feel free to edit your question when you've got more specific, targeted requirements, though. As it currently stands all it will field is aimless suggestions instead of constructive problem-solving.

Comment: It won't be as 'fun' as it sounds, but you could re-create Pun-Pun http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Pun_Pun

Comment: I strongly suggest you and your DM (and gaming group) to trace a line over what is or isn't allowed. My personal suggestion for "combo, but not broken" is to avoid cycled repetitions of the same effect like the ones needed to build infinite skills on an Omniscifier build or near-infinite abilities on Pun-Pun. Without such line, I'm just guessing your only chance is to be a team of pun-puns, facing pun-pun opponents, which I deem to be **very** unfun.

Comment: In order for us to reopen this question, you need to define the limits of the game in terms of the available literature.

Comment: @Zachiel "[B]e a team of pun-puns, facing pun-pun opponents". mybrainisfullof.jpg